# Does log-concave approximable distribution satisfy transportation-cost inequality?

Tags: pr.probability, approximation-theory, measure-concentration, geometric-probability

> **Definition:** Recall that a distribution $\mu$ on  $\mathbb R^d$ is said to be log-convave with constant $c > 0$, if density $d\nu \propto e^{-V}dvol$ satisfying the curvature condition
>   $$
> \operatorname{Hess}_x(V) \succeq cI_d,\text{ for all }x \in \mathbb R^d.
> $$

Now, It is known that a distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^d$ which has finite moment and density not supported on an affine subspace can be approximated with a log-concave distribution $\nu$ ([Lemma 2.1 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3448.pdf)).

## Question

Would such a distribution $\mu$ then satisfy a transportation-cost inequality for the Wasserstein $2$-distance (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309372/78539) for 
definitions, just in case) ?

Comment: Could someone kindly explain why this question was downvoted ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try again.

The theorem of Otto and Villani implies that every distribution $\nu$ which is log-concave in the sense you define satisfies a transportation-cost inequality.

There are many distributions $\mu$ with finite moments and density supported everywhere which do not satisfy a transportation-cost inequality.  Since a TCI in particular implies subgaussian concentration, any distribution $\mu$ which has larger than Gaussian tails will fail to satisfy a TCI.  One such distribution $\mu$ is the exponential distribution.  But by the theorem of Otto and Villani, there is no such distribution $\mu$ which is also log-concave in the sense you define.

Whichever question you mean to ask, the answer is in the above two paragraphs.

Comment: I think there might be some misunderstanding here. By log-concave, what is actually meant is **log strongly-convave**.  This is usual language. That is, this are measures with density of the form $e^{-V(x)}dx$ for some $\mathcal C^2$ potential $V:\mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with Hessian $\operatorname{Hess}V(x) \succeq \rho I_d$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^d$.  See Bobkov et Goetze 1999. No doubt,  the exponential disitrbution on $\mathbb R^p$ doesn't have the TCI, which is fine since it's not log-concave in the sense abovE.

Comment: That is not the standard terminology in any source I've seen, including the paper you linked in the question, which defines log-concave to mean of the form $e^{-V(x)} dx$ for $V$ convex (not necessarily strictly convex).

Comment: But this is beside the point for the question you asked: a distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ which has finite moment and density not supported on an affine subspace typically will not satisfy a TCI.

Comment: Well, this presumption is just a restatement of the question, in negative form. Any counterexample ?

Comment: @dohmatob: Yes: an exponential distribution has finite moments and density not supported on an affine subspace, but does not satisfy a TCI.

Comment: Well, I don't see the point repeating the same inapplicable example over and over. As I said, by log-concave, I actually mean **log strongly-concave**.  In particular the exponential distribution **is not** log-strongly concave.  Please see previous comments. I'll include this precision explicitly in the question in hope that it maybe clearer.

Comment: @dohmatob: Please clarify the question.  As stated, you did not assume $\mu$ to be log-concave in any sense (although you cite a result that it can be approximated in some sense by a log-concave measure), and then asked if it must satisfy a TCI.  The exponential distribution is an example of a measure $\mu$ which satisfies the assumptions you stated and does not satisfy a TCI.

Comment: On the other hand, if you mean to assume that $\mu$ is itself log strongly-concave, then yes, it does satisfy a TCI.  This was first proved by Otto and Villani, as you stated yourself in your other question linked here.

Comment: the last edit I made to the question got screwed and the definition was inserted at the end / middle instead of the beginning. Fixed. So the question is whether a distribution $\nu$ can approximated by a log-strongly concave distribution $\mu$,  does $\nu$ itself satisfy TCI ? Not that $\nu$ satisfies TCI (consequence of results by Bobkov et Goetze 1999; Otto et Villani 2000). The question is whether this transfers to $\nu$ (of course with perhaps a degraded TCI constant).

Comment: Okay, so I've removed the use of terminology which is inconsistent with yours from my answer, and the answer to your question is unambiguously no, with the exponential distribution as a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I think we simply don't understand each other and it won't get any better.  No offence taken. The exponential distribution $d\mu \propto e^{-\lambda x}1_{x \ge 0}dx$ is **not** a counterexample. It's **not** log **strongly-concave**.

Comment: It's a counter-example because while it is not log-strongly concave, it can be approximated by log-strongly concave functions (that's what Lemma 2.1 states). Therefore, it is an example of a distribution that can be approximated by a log strongly-concave function that does not satisfy a TCI.

Comment: OK, ya makes sense, and it indeed is a counterexample. Upvoted. There was a strong inductive bias in my previous comment, as I thought your  comment was just a recycling of previous comments based on the misunderstanding (language).  My bad.